# Browser Resize and Chrome Inspect shows different Layouts , how to fix this issue using media query?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, google-chrome, web-inspector

I have add css and media queries for width of screens thats ranging from 320 to a max width above 1440 , When i take the webpage using chromes inspect everything shows fine , but when i resize the browser the page layouts breaks apart for the same size , for example if i resize the browser to 992 x 442 as browser resize , the layout breaks , but if i use the same resolution while inspecting in chrome the page layout is prefect.

What is happening over here ? and can i fix this issue?

```
@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 769px)
and (max-device-width: 991px) {
    .fix-feedback{height: 80px;}
    .col-f-lt {
        width: 14% !important;
        height: 80px;
    }
    .col-f-lt p{line-height: 53px;}
    .col-f-rt {
        width: 83% !important;
    }
    .btn-send-fb {
        margin-top: 1px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}

@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 768px)
and (max-device-width: 1199px) {

    .navbar-nav>li {
        display: inline-block;
        float: inherit;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        text-align: center;
        float: none;
        margin: 6px auto;
    }
}

@media (width: 768px){
    .col-f-lt{  width: 16%;  float: left;  background: #13929e;  padding: 33px 20px;  margin-right: 10px; }
    .col-f-rt {  margin: 2px 0 0;  width: 80%;  float: left;  padding: 10px 0 15px;    }
    .sav-btnn{ display: inline-block; width: 100%;}
    .sav-btnn a{ display: table; margin: 0 auto; float: inherit !important;   margin-bottom: 10px;}
    .table-responsive {
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
        -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    .btn-send-fb {
        margin-top: 1px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post a minimal code snippet so we can see what is wrong

Comment: Got your mail. You should update the question with a code sample. Also, do not communicate over personal mail when it comes to posts at SO. If you want to hire me for work would be a different story.

Comment: How can i show a sample code ,when idon't know what the problem is with the css , which part would you want me to paster here , and is there anyorder in which the media queries are written?

Comment: You should post a minimal part, that reproduce the issue, and how you find that part I can't say, though what I do in such cases, is simply removing litle by little of the markup and see what/when things change. When it comes to if media query's order in CSS matters, yes, it matters very much, so you could start with posting those.

Comment: Hi , i have added the snippet , can you please check now

Comment: The `min-device-width` is deprecated, change to `min-width` (and the same for `max-device-width`).

Comment: The last query use only _width_ in (`width: 768`), when do you want that to kick in?

Comment: I think (width: 768) i need to be used in between 768 and less to 480 px , i am actually confused , while i inspect using chrome the layout is ok , but when i resize browser it some media queries are not taking in.

Comment: Did my answer worked and can be accepted?

Comment: Yes , it worked , the device in between was the issue , thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, `min-device-width` and `max-device-width` is deprecated, use `min-width` and `max-width`.

The problem here is that your first query start at 769px and ends at 991px, then your second start at 768px, even before the first one started, so when the screen is between 769px and 991px both will be applied.

If they are to be applied one after the other, change the seconds `min-width` to 992px

Based on a comment, change the 3rd to `@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 768px){`.

*Note, when both `min-width`/`max-width` are used like this, it won't matter their position in the CSS, though it is recommended to order them from low to high, to make it easier to follow what happens to who and when.*

```
@media only screen
and (min-width: 769px)
and (max-width: 991px) {
    .fix-feedback{height: 80px;}
    .col-f-lt {
        width: 14% !important;
        height: 80px;
    }
    .col-f-lt p{line-height: 53px;}
    .col-f-rt {
        width: 83% !important;
    }
    .btn-send-fb {
        margin-top: 1px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}

@media only screen
and (min-width: 992px)
and (max-width: 1199px) {

    .navbar-nav>li {
        display: inline-block;
        float: inherit;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        text-align: center;
        float: none;
        margin: 6px auto;
    }
}

@media only screen
and (min-width: 480px)
and (max-width: 768px){
    .col-f-lt{  width: 16%;  float: left;  background: #13929e;  padding: 33px 20px;  margin-right: 10px; }
    .col-f-rt {  margin: 2px 0 0;  width: 80%;  float: left;  padding: 10px 0 15px;    }
    .sav-btnn{ display: inline-block; width: 100%;}
    .sav-btnn a{ display: table; margin: 0 auto; float: inherit !important;   margin-bottom: 10px;}
    .table-responsive {
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
        -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    .btn-send-fb {
        margin-top: 1px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help man , i will do as you said and will update if it worked or not